# How to copy a SQLAlchemy query object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've tried copy.deepcopy, but get this error:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 93, in **newobj**
    return cls.**new**(cls, *args)
TypeError: object.**new**(psycopg2._psycopg.type) is not safe, use psycopg2._psycopg.type.**new**()

Why do I want to copy? Because I have two queries that I want to run that are almost, but not quite identical. I've applied half a dozen filters that are the same, and now I want to apply one filter, execute that, and then "rollback" and apply the other filter and execute that.

I tried pickling and unpickling as a workaround, but pickle doesn't work on function objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you add a .filter() or something similar to a query it returns a copy of the query. See the docs here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter

I guess you can use that functionality for your case:

```
query = session.query(Customer)
main_query = query.filter(Customer.size > 150)
query1 = main_query.filter(Customer.age > 50)
query2 = main_query.filter(Customer.age < 30)
```

query1 would return you all the customer that are bigger than 150 and older than 50

query2 would return you all the customers that are bigger than 150 and younger than 30

Comment: Hmm, I was doing something along those lines, but I was getting an error that suggested it was still referencing the original query object. Of course, for some reason, I can't replicate it now despite spending half an hour debugging it earlier.

Comment: Hyperlink seems updated now, new doc can be found here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter

Comment: Also it seems you can achieve the same thing when using join. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join